# Mobil Navigation disappears

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I am trying to figure out why when I put my browser in mobile view, that my mobile nav just disappears. I cannot seem to pinpoint what is causing the issue but when my navigation is in mobile view it is gone every single time I make my browser smaller. If anyone can help me figure this issue out it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

I had to put my code in a JsFiddle because it was just a little too long. Apologies for this, however, here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/99sc49a3/1/

Here is my html because stack wont let me post without code:

```html
<header>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-7LkWEzqTdpEfELxcZZlS6wAx5Ff13zZ83lYO2/ujj7g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="SlickNav-master/dist/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#menu').slicknav();
    });
  </script>
  <nav>
    <div id="fix">
      <ul class="main-nav" id="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="portfolio.html" class="logo"><img id="logo" src="logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#logowheader">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#recent">Skills</a></li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">
        <li><a href="#description">About</a></li></button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Work</a>
            <a href="education2.html">Education</a>

          </div>

        </div>
        <li><a href="#iwant">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: In the developer console can you see what class is applied to the menu once it disapears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is causing it

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #menu {
    display: none;   /* this line, right here */
    z-index: 1000;
  }
}
```

On taking a closer look at your fiddle, it appears you are using `slicknav.js` for your menu and the problem is you are calling `.slicknav()` before loading it. 
Please see the [`updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/99sc49a3/2/) with a working example. I placed the `.slicknav()` call on `window.load` event, when the slicknav has already been loaded.

Here's how I did it:

```js
(function(){
    $(window).on('load', function(){
        $('#menu').slicknav();
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! While this keeps the desktop nav open in mobile it is supposed to change into my mobile nav which it still is refusing to do. @Andrei Gheorghiu

Comment: I do have this coded for mobile view and it works on my other pages in desktop and mobile. However, something about this code is throwing off my mobile navigation from showing and I included the new code from this page. @Andrei Gheorghiu

Comment: See updated answer. You're calling `slicknav()` before loading it. Also you need to make sure jQuery is loaded when you make this call.

Comment: Oh my gosh this worked! I understand now what went wrong and I truly appreciate your help with this! Thank you!